# Ubuntu 14.04 unable to install/find mysqldump

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, mysqldump

I have a VPS with a working CMS (Ubuntu 14.04 LAMP).
CMS is perfectly working, but I'm not able to automate back-up (rsnapshot witch scripts calling mysqldump) cause I can't find mysqldump in the system.

If I type mysqldump I get:

```
The program 'mysqldump' can be found in the following packages:
 * mysql-client-5.5
 * mariadb-client-5.5
 * mysql-client-5.6
 * percona-xtradb-cluster-client-5.5
Try: apt-get install <selected package>
```

If I try to install mysql-client or mysql-client-5.5 (apt install mysql-client-5.5) I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mysql-client-5.5 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

mysql server is correctly working, but I'm not able to install mysqldump

Any suggestion?

Thank you

Comment: What says `dpkg -S /usr/bin/mysqldump`

Answer (score -1):

Solved by disinstalling and reinstalling lamp metapackage through tasksel

Unfortnately this caused a little service outage, fortunately less than 2 minutes